# Get vs simple present

Tags: grammar

I need to tell my son that I will close the door and come with you...Which of the below two sentences is more appropriate..

1.will close the door first and then go..
2.Will get the door closed first and then go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I will close the door ...
> 2. I will get the door closed ...

The basic meaning is the same for both statements, but the second one, using "get", implies either that the task of closing the door is a process that takes some significant time and effort (Perhaps there is a hurricane blowing outside, or the door just fell off its hinges.), *or* that, in order to get the job done, you will "get" someone else to do it.

In normal circumstances, we wouldn't use the "get it done" expression for closing a door, but for other activities it might be appropriate.

> 1. I will fix the door, and then we'll go.
> 2. I will get the door fixed, and
>      then we'll go.

The second one might even mean that you will call a handyman to "get it fixed" before your journey.